# How to pass the selected $index in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pug

I want to upload image and show up in the page. I have 5 image so there is 5 arrays and I'm using ng-repeat to show it out.

Below is my html in jade form:

```
                form.form-horizontal       
                    .form-group(ng-repeat="runningText in runningTexts")
                        .col-md-3
                            label.control-label Image {{$index+1}}
                            .image-upload-area.label-centerleft
                                p(onclick="$('#imageFile').click()") Click me to change
                                img.loading(ng-show="isUploading" src="/img/loading.gif")    
                                img.img-responsive.clickable(ng-src="{{runningText.image != '' ? '/img/' + runningText.image : '/img/logo_d.png'}}")                                    

                form#imageUpload(enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/api/admin/display/image" ng-upload="uploadDone(content)" method="post")
                    input#imageFile(type="file" name="image" onChange="$('#imageSubmit').click();return false;" style="display:none")
                    input#imageSubmit(type="submit" ng-click="isUploading = true"  style="display:none")
```

Below is my controller in my js file:

```
    loadData = function(){  //page load function
    $http.get(apiPath)
        .success(function(data){  
            if (data != null){       
                $scope.runningTexts = data.displaySetting.runningText;
            }
        })  
    }  

    $scope.uploadDone = function(data) {  // upload finished function
    $scope.runningTexts[0].image = data.path;  // Problem here!!
    $scope.isUploading = false;
};
```

How do I pass the index that I choose in the html and put it back in the $scope.runningTexts[0].image. Now I'm using 0, so every image I upload will show up in array 0 only. How do I do it if I upload to array 1, or 2 and so on?

Comment: like this ng-click="loadData ($index)"

Comment: @Sajeetharan, my problem is during upload finish, how do my uploadDone function know which array I have uploaded to? I load all the array out in one time using ng-repeat. But during uploading, I only upload to one array at a time. That's my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a function at click event of Image and pass $index as a parameter to that.

```
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="page in pages">
        <a ng-class="{ testClass: $index == pageNumber }" ng-click="setPageNumber($index)">{{ page }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.pages = [
    'Page One',
    'Page Two',
    'Page Three'
];

$scope.pageNumber = 0;
$scope.setPageNumber = function(index) {
    $scope.pageNumber = index;
    console.log(index)
}
```

});

You can check this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/razh/NFNvc/